# Comparing Strings using Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
HelloThere = ["Hello There", "Hello there", "hello there"]
for word in HelloThere:
    if (message.content.lower().count(word) > 0) and (message.author.id != 712885407993561169):
        await message.channel.send("General Kenobi")
```

I am trying to test to see if a string contains a certain key phrase. If the string contains something like, "Why Hello THeRe" then it must satisfy the `if statement`.

The code returns General Kenobi correctly, however, I want to have good code practice and do not understand why the list of words (`HelloThere = ["Hello There", "Hello there", "hello there"]`) only works when it's in this certain order and number. If for example I just have it as `Hello There = ["Hello There"]` and test for that, it won't work.

Comment: I don't understand your question. In the former case `HelloThere` is a `list` while in the latter it's a `str`. The `for ... in` loop will obviously work differently in each case.

Comment: how so, because I want to understand how this works

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow format is not suitable to explain this, but any introductory Python tutorial would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing the lowercased version of the message (`.lower()`) so the variants with uppercase letters can never match.  The point of using `.lower()` in the first place is to avoid having to do any of this -- just test the lowercase phrase against the lowercased message so you can ignore capitalization entirely.

```
if "hello there" in message.content.lower() and message.author.id != 712885407993561169:
    await message.channel.send("General Kenobi")
```

If you did have multiple phrases to check, it'd be more simple to use `any`:

```
phrases = {"hello there", "you are a bold one"}
if message.author.id != 712885407993561169 and any(
    p in message.content.lower() for p in phrases
):
    await message.channel.send("General Kenobi")
```